# Getting NoSuchElementError When Checking to See if a modal is open or not

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I have a test where I am trying to check and see if a modal is open or not. If the modal is open, the test works fine, when it is not open the test fails with a `NoSuchElementError` exception.

Here is my current version of my test:

```
            fit('Share is actually shared', () => {
            console.log(`\n ### Share is actually shared ${entity.name} ### \n`)
            listView.clickSharing(entity.name)
            const sharedWithBefore = sharing.sharedUsers.count()
            sharing.createShare(sharee)
            sharing.shareButton.click()

            // Handle 'Share with Everyone'
            const isPresent = browser.isElementPresent(sharing.modal.getWebElement())
            isPresent.then(result => {
                console.log('is the modal present: ' + result)
                if (result) {
                    sharing.modalAcceptButton.click()
                }
            })


            const sharedWithAfter = sharing.sharedUsers.count()
            Promise.all([sharedWithBefore, sharedWithAfter]).then(results => {
                expect(results[0] != results[1]).toBe(true)
            })
            sharing.title.click()
            common.escapeFromBody()
        })
```

The problem in the block following the `// Handle`Share with Everyone` comment.

I have tried doing the following and none of it works, if the modal does not appear it simply fails.

```
const isPresent = sharing.modal.isPresent()
if (isPresent) {
    sharing.modalAcceptButton.click()
} //THIS FAILS WHEN MODAL NOT PRESENT

const isPresent = sharing.modal.isPresent()
isPresent.then(result => {
    if (result) {
        sharing.modalAcceptButton.click()
    } //THIS FAILS WHEN MODAL NOT PRESENT
})

const isPresent = sharing.modal.isPresent()
const isDisplayed = sharing.modal.isDisplayed()
if (isPresent && isDisplayed) {
    sharing.modalAcceptButton.click()
} //THIS FAILS WHEN MODAL NOT PRESENT

// THIS ALSO FAILS
const isPresent = browser.isElementPresent(sharing.modal.getWebElement())
isPresent.then(present => {
    if (present) {
                    sharing.modalAcceptButton.click()
                    const sharedWithAfter = sharing.sharedUsers.count()
                    Promise.all([sharedWithBefore, sharedWithAfter]).then(results => {
                        expect(results[0] != results[1]).toBe(true)
                    })
                } else {
                    const sharedWithAfter = sharing.sharedUsers.count()
                    Promise.all([sharedWithBefore, sharedWithAfter]).then(results => {
                        expect(results[0] != results[1]).toBe(true)
                    })
                }
            })

// This is likewise failing
                const isPresent = browser.isElementPresent(sharing.modal.getWebElement())
            isPresent.then(present => {
                try {
                    if (present) {
                        sharing.modalAcceptButton.click()
                        const sharedWithAfter = sharing.sharedUsers.count()
                        Promise.all([sharedWithBefore, sharedWithAfter]).then(results => {
                            expect(results[0] != results[1]).toBe(true)
                        })
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchElementError) {
                    console.log('The Modal is not present continuing')
                    const sharedWithAfter = sharing.sharedUsers.count()
                    Promise.all([sharedWithBefore, sharedWithAfter]).then(results => {
                        expect(results[0] != results[1]).toBe(true)
                    })

                }
            })
```

I am not really sure what to try from here. If the modal is not present then the test simply fails. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I finally solved it:

```
sharing.modal.isPresent().then(present => {
    if (present) {
        sharing.modalAcceptButton.click()
    } else {
        console.log('The Modal is not present continuing')
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with **sharing** and **sharing.modal** has some value as Is it Undefined then you can proceed as you wish. 
like: 
`if(sharing != undefined)
{
   if(sharing.modal != undefined)
}`